# Previous 10 Week Calculation in Excel

Tags: excel

I have three columns "Fiscal Year" "Fiscal Week" and "Current Week" as shown in the below table and I would like to identify only previous 10 weeks.

For E.g. If my Current Week is FW-8 2016 then 8 should be blank and previous 10 weeks should be updated. Below is the table for your reference.

[image]

Similarly if my Current week is FW- 9 2016 then FW-9 2016 and FW-50 2015 will be blank.

[image]

I just wanna see previous 10 weeks.

Could we write a excel formula to get the results. Tried my luck using "If" "And" function but was not successful. I beleive we can achieve this using "IF" condition.

It would of great help if anyone can help me to achieve the results.

Thanks,
Ganesh

Comment: Try `=IF(AND(B2-A2<=10,B2-A2>0),A2,"")`

Comment: Excellent! It worked like a gem... Thanks:)

Comment: Hi Scott, The above mentioned formula will work only for the current year. During the Fiscal week 1 2016 we will compare previous weeks of 2015 then the above mentioned formula do not work. For E.g.  During year 2016 FW 7, current week would 7 and previous 10 weeks would be 2015 FW-50 ; 2015 FW-51 ; 2015 FW-52 ; 2016 FW-1 ; 2016 FW-2 ; 2016 FW-3 ; 2016 FW-4 ; 2016 FW-5 ; 2016 FW-6; 2016 FW-7. I need blank only in Current week 7 but if I use the above mentioned formula it will give me blank for FW-50, 51 and 52 as well. Please help

Comment: There are no years shown in your screenshots.  Where should the formula find the year?

Comment: Hi Tim Williams, I sincerely apologize, I have the changed the screen shots. It would be of great help if you could help me achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up something like this:

[image]

So in E2 I have the current fiscal year and in F2 the current fiscal week.

Then in C2 I put the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(MATCH($F$2,IF($A$1:$A$10000=$E$2,$B$1:$B$10000),0)-ROW()<=10,MATCH($F$2,IF($A$1:$A$10000=$E$2,$B$1:$B$10000),0)-ROW()>0),B2,"")
```

This is an Array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then copy the formula down the desired length.

I limited the search area to 10,000 rows.  If you need more change it.

One note:  This requires that the data be sorted like it is in your example; Fiscal Year then Fiscal week.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks a ton for your, i was able to achieve the results now. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ganesh please consider marking as correct.  hit the green check by the answer.